# How to use ajax to call back results from a php form validation

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```html
<h1>Form Validation</h1>

<form id="PersonForm">

Name: <input type="text" id="name" name="name"> <br>

Postal Code: <input type="text" id="postal" name="postal"> <br>

Phone Number: <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone"> <br>

Address: <input type="text" id="address" name="address"> <br>

<input type="submit">

</form>

<a href="frontend.html">Refresh</a> 
<a id="InsertDefault" href="">Insert Default Data</a> 
<br>

<ul id="errors"></ul>
<p id="success"></p>

</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>

 if ($_REQUEST['act'] == 'validate')
{
  $validateData = array();

  if (preg_match("/^[A-Za-z]{3,20}$/",$_REQUEST['name'])) $validateData['name'] = 1;
  else $validateData['name'] = 0;

  if (preg_match("/^[0-9]{10}$/",$_REQUEST['phone'])) $validateData['phone'] = 1;
  else $validateData['phone'] = 0;

  if (preg_match("/^[A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9]$/",
                             $_REQUEST['postal'])) $validateData['postal'] = 1;
  else $validateData['postal'] = 0;

  if (preg_match("/^[0-9]{3} [A-Za-z]{3,10} Street$/",
                             $_REQUEST['address'])) $validateData['address'] = 1;
  else $validateData['address'] = 0;

  echo json_encode($validateData);
}
else echo "Should not happen";

?>
</html>
  

$("#PersonForm").submit(function()
  {
     // Clear any success or error messages
     $("#success").html("");
     $("#errors").empty();

    
    return false;
  });  

});
```

How would I go about calling back the results from the `$validatedata` array and then create an error message for each validation that `= 0`. Also how would I go about creating a success message if the results of the `validatedata` are all `= 1`.
I need to put the callback function into the `.submit(function)` at the very bottom but I have no clue how to go about doing this.